# Installing OracleXE on Ubuntu using Salt

Tags: salt-stack

I recently started using SaltStack was able to install java + tomcat successfully.

Now i want to install OracleXE on Ubuntu. You can probably imagine that I'm kinda lost, Can't find anything useful on installing and configuring OracleXE through SaltStack , so I was wondering if anyone knew how to do it.

Comment: Let's start with, how would you normally install OracleXE. Is it through `apt-get` or via a custom command? Where do you get the package? Does it need to be compile? From there you can decide the approach to take with salt.

Comment: Thanks for responding ... i saw this blog ... http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/ ... it has following broad categories .. 1) install java_home 2) make installer123.deb from installer123.rpm 3) push the necessary conf files 4) run the  deb installer 5) run the oracle configuration wizard .... 1-4 are more or less doable not sure of step#5 ... your thoughts ?